# Is it possible to supress a function redeclaration error in PHP?

Tags: php, function, redeclare

I wonder if it is possible to supress errors in PHP like when redeclaring functions, so the execution wont break and the script would just use the first time declared function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just because your question got closed does not mean you should ask it again with your intention "masked".

Comment: Yes, a duplicate, but at least it gave me an answer |-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wonder if it is possible to supress errors in PHP...

PHP has many options to *supress* errors, such as the `error_reporting()` function and `display_errors` option in `php.ini`.

> ...so the execution wont break and the script would just use the first time declared function?

Re-declaring functions is a fatal error in PHP, which you generally can not gracefully recover from.

You *could* preprocess the source code, removing duplicate function declarations.

Comment: He can do `if( !is_callable( 'foo')){function foo(){}}`

Comment: @Vyktor True, but that isn't suppressing any errors. It may work for the OP though.

Comment: Yes I know but it may give him easy solution to his problem. What do you mean by OP?

Comment: @Vyktor Original Poster. I used his previous question for context too... he wants to redefine ionCube encoded functions and let their redefinitions fail silently.

Comment: btw: there's http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php this little thing

Answer (score 3):

It's probably not the best idea to suppress errors, but there is certain logic you can use in your code to circumvent them.

Check to see if a function has previously been declared:

```
if(!function_exists("my_function"))
{
   function my_function() 
   {
     // ... do stuff
   }
}
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php

Answer (score 0):

Suppressing error messages is generally bad idea.
It is considered good practice to repair the error instead. *Hint:* it is *not* as hard as it seems.